# How to write custom messages on passed tests with jasmine and protractor?

Tags: testing, jasmine, protractor

I'm looking a way to add custom messages on succeeded tests with protractor and jasmine.
There're many ways to customize messages on failure, like jasmine-custom-message node package or simply:

```
expect(column.get(0)).toEqual("7", "This is not something I've expected");
```

But I haven't found a way to add custom messages on success. I'm using protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter to generate my reports, but successful tests only display a "passed" or "0 failure" messages and I'd like to be more explicit about what am I testing and why the tests passed.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing built into jasmine for that: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1127..

Answer (score -1):

You want to write a custom matcher for Jasmine. You want to include them in the protractor.conf.js file so they are accessible over the entire project

https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html

Here is an example of comparing numbers with the message printing off if there is an error. The error if you run this will be `Expected 7 to be 8 (Expected Error)`. Note, this is including it in the spec using the `beforeEach`.

```
var customMatchers = {
  toBeEqualWithMessage: function(util, customEqualityTesters) {
    return {
      compare: function(actual, expected, message) {
        var result = {};
        result.pass = util.equals(actual, expected, customEqualityTesters);
        if (!result.pass) {
          result.message = "Expected " + actual + " to be " + expected + " (" + message + ")";
        }
        return result;
      }
    };
  }
};

describe('Custom Matcher', function(){
  beforeEach(function() { jasmine.addMatchers(customMatchers);});

  it('should use a matcher', function(){
    expect(7).toBeEqualWithMessage(7,"No error because they match");
    expect(7).not.toBeEqualWithMessage(8,"No error because of the 'not'");
    expect(7).toBeEqualWithMessage(8,"Expected Error");
  });
});
```

FYI: The doc has a result.message for a passing case, but I don't know where that is used, maybe a verbose print out.

Comment: How does this custom matcher help to display success messages? Looks like it works the same way as usual matchers, displaying the message only on failure. Please explain in more detail.